# Android notification how to create play /pause button?

Tags: java, android

I am not able to create bigger play/pause button in Decorated notification.
How can I do it?
Here is what I have:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {

        if (statusPlay){
            notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,FOREGROUND_CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_books_mini2)
                    .setContentTitle(tmpTitle)
                    .setContentText(""+notificationPercentage + "%  " + tmpAuthor)
                    .setLargeIcon(artwork)
                    .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_TRANSPORT) //CATEGORY_SERVICE
                    .addAction(R.drawable.prev10w,"prev10",lPendingSeekPrevIntent)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_pause_white,"pause",lPendingPauseIntent)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.next10w,"next10",lPendingSeekNextIntent)
                    .setStyle(new androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.DecoratedMediaCustomViewStyle()
                            .setShowActionsInCompactView(0,1,2)
                            .setMediaSession(mediaSession.getSessionToken())
                    )
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
                    .setColorized(true)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent) 
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                    .setOngoing(true);

        }else {
            notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, FOREGROUND_CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_books_mini2)
                    .setContentTitle(tmpTitle)
                    .setContentText("" + notificationPercentage + "%  " + tmpAuthor)
                    .setLargeIcon(artwork)
                    .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_TRANSPORT)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.prev10w,"prev10",lPendingSeekPrevIntent)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_white,"play",lPendingPlayIntent)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.next10w,"next10",lPendingSeekNextIntent)
                    .setStyle(new androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.DecoratedMediaCustomViewStyle()
                            .setShowActionsInCompactView(0,1,2)
                            .setMediaSession(mediaSession.getSessionToken())
                    )
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
                    .setColorized(true)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent) 
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    ;

            ;
        }


    }
```

This looks like this with small buttons on bottom:
[image]

But required is this bigger button:
[image]

In official poages of android development ,they recommend to use this Decorated Media Custom View in notifications due to restricted space and colors to be visible with texts. Many thanks for help.

Comment: Why dont you use a custom view?

Comment: Problem is I dont know how, because dimensions width and height are very precisely determined, I could not find how. And mobile phones are each diffenet...

Comment: You dont have to bother about the width. It'll be full my default. And the height can be `wrap-content`.

Comment: I saw on more apps with same button on right side, so it must be some piece of code...This I would appreciate :)

Comment: You can see recommendation with Caution on bottom of this page! >  https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/custom-notification

Answer (score 0):

To show this play/pause control you should create a media session and use PlaybackState.
Something like this

```
  override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        initVideoPlayer()
        initMediaSession()
    }
    private fun initMediaSession() {
        mediaSession = MediaSessionCompat(this, "PlayVideoSession")
        mediaSession?.setCallback(object : MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {
            override fun onPlay() {
                audioManager?.requestAudioFocus(
                    audioFocusChangeListener,
                    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN
                )
                exoPlayer?.play()
                showNotification()
            }

            override fun onPause() {
                exoPlayer?.pause()
            }
        })
        mediaSession?.isActive = true
    }

    private fun createNotification(): Notification? {
        if (mediaSession == null) return null
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel = NotificationChannel(
                NotificationHelper.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID_PLAYER_CONTROLS,
                getString(R.string.notification_name_player_controls),
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
            )
            channel.description = getString(R.string.notification_description_player_controls)
            val notificationManager = getSystemService(
                NotificationManager::class.java
            )
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }

        val mediaStyle = androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
            .setMediaSession(mediaSession!!.sessionToken)
            .setShowActionsInCompactView()

        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this,
            NotificationHelper.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID_PLAYER_CONTROLS
        )
            .setStyle(mediaStyle)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_play_notification)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)

        return notificationBuilder.build()

    }

  private fun getActions(): Long {
        return if (exoPlayer?.isPlaying == true) PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PAUSE else PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY

    }
```

I strongly recommend you to read this [post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/08/playing-nicely-with-media-controls.html)